# Magento 2 : Sales Order Service Class?

Tags: magento2, sales-order

What is the alternative of below in magento 2

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo $creditmemo */
$creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice, $data);
```